# NoSuchMethodException when downloading images from s3

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, eclipse, amazon-s3

I am trying to download images from S3 server with the following code:

```
S3Object obj = s3.getObject(BUCKETNAME, path);
S3ObjectInputStream objContent = obj.getObjectContent();
```

However, an exception is thrown at line 2. The exception is “NoSuchMethodException was thrown when disabling normalizeUri. This indicates you are using an old version (<4.5.8) of Apache http client. It is recommended to use http client version >= 4.5.9 to avoid breaking change introduced in Apache client 4.5.7 and the latency in exception handling.”

I am using eclipse and Java. I have added the following libraries to my user libraries:

- Aws-Java-sdk-kms-1.12.14.jar
- Aws-Java-sdk-s3-1.12.14.jar
- Aws-Java-sdk-core-1.12.14.jar

Anyone come across this issue?

Comment: Which Apache http client version are you using? That's what the error message refers to.

Comment: @nitind I didn’t include any Apache http client libraries in my project. Do I have to include them?

Comment: Are you sure about that? They're among the requirements for the jars you listed. And why a year old version of the SDK?